# Python example repeating answer during quiz and not at end

Tags: python

and I apologies for the simple nature of my question.

Im working my way through "Hello World", Computer programming for Kids and Beginners - By Warren and Carter Sande.

The first chapters second example is this numeric example, of a pirate number quiz. Programming language is Python.

Its supposed to allow 6 guesses, unless the correct number is guessed first. I guess for you people the code would be self explanatory.

```
import random

secret = random.randint(1,99)
guess = 0
tries = 0

print "AHOY! I'm the dread Pirate Roberts, and I have a secret!"
print "It's a number from 1 to 99. I'll give you 6 tries."

while guess != secret and tries < 6:
guess = input("What's yer guess? ")
if guess < secret:
    print "Too low, ye scurvy dog!"
elif guess > secret:
    print "Too high, landlubber!"
tries = tries +1
if guess == secret:
    print "Avast! Ye got it! Found my secret, ye did!"
else:
    print "No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!"
    print "The secret number was", secret
```

But when I run it, it tells me what the answer is after each guess, which its not supposed to. Its supposed to wait until the end.

I just cant figure out what I have done wrong. I have checked each line, or at least, I think I have.

If someone could point out where I have gone wrong, that would be great.

Comment: Could you fix your Python indentation? It doesn't currently run

Comment: Indent the code in the while loop. The part you want to loop over should all be indented by the same amount - say 4 spaces

Answer (score 3):

Proper indentation is key. Make sure you indent the stuff inside the loop, and leave the stuff after the loop un-indented.

```
while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = input("What's yer guess? ")
    if guess < secret:
        print "Too low, ye scurvy dog!"
    elif guess > secret:
        print "Too high, landlubber!"
    tries = tries + 1

if guess == secret:
    print "Avast! Ye got it! Found my secret, ye did!"
else:
    print "No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!"
    print "The secret number was", secret
```

Comment: Thank you. So would that be the code between the while statement and the elif statement? I haven't got up to loops yet.

Answer (score 0):

A nicer way to write this might be. Then you don't have to set `guess` to `0` outside the loop

```
for tries in range(1, 6):
    guess = input("What's yer guess? ")
    if guess < secret:
        print "Too low, ye scurvy dog!"
    elif guess > secret:
        print "Too high, landlubber!"
    else:
        print "Avast! Ye got it! Found my secret, ye did!"
        break 
else:
    print "No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!"
    print "The secret number was", secret
```